# I'm trying to do the notification every hour but want to populate from database, I have working code but not up to one hour for next notification

Tags: java, android

I want to make a notification app that will alert based on data from the database I have done the app that is notifying, I want it to be every one hour but the notification is not up to an hour before another one trigger.
here is the code

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){

 @Override
 public void run() {
   while(true){
     try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
       public void run() {
       AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
       asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, email, day, hourToPass);
       }
                    });
                    counter++;
                    Thread.sleep(3600000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

Here is the trigger code

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LoginActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 3600000, pendingIntent);
```

Is under onPostExcute of AsyncTask

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
                        asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, email, day, hourToPass);
                    }
                });
                counter++;
                Thread.sleep(3600000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};

private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        String jsonResult = "";
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", params[1]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("day", params[2]));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", params[3]));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.v("Passing Data = ", nameValuePairs.toString());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);
        if(result.equals("") || result == null){

           Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);

        JSONObject resGet = null;
        try {
            resGet = new JSONObject(result);
            course_code = resGet.getString("course_code");
            course_title = resGet.getString("course_title");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(jsonResult == 0){
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "No Notification for this hour", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(jsonResult == 1){
            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            alarmIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("email", email);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("time", hourToPass);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("day", day);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("loguser", loggedUser);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("stat", status);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("lv", level);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("course_code", course_code);
            alarmIntent.putExtra("course_title", course_title);
            sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LoginActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 3600000, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `Handler` as :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

And in the end of your `Runnable()` call this : `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000*60*60);`

Working example could be :

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
           asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, email, day, hourToPass);
           //To repeat it every hour
           handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000*60*60);

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000*60*60); //call this when you want to start doing the work
```

Comment: I tested this but the app didn't notify at all

Comment: @Olizy What did you try? I tested this code with a `Toast` and it works, just copy and paste the code from my answer, and add the `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000*60*60);` wherever you want to start counting, first test it with 5 seconds for instance to see if it works for you.

Comment: @Olizy What's the status of the question is it solved?

Comment: if my answer helped to you feel free to upvote and mark the answer as a correct one, otherwise post whatever you needed to solve your problem and mark yours as a correct so we let other people know what helped to you :D

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using an [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), unless I have misunderstood your requirements.

Submitting your runnables to an executor would allow you to schedule the execution hourly, and you would be able to guarantee the execution time, irrespective of how long the previous execution took which would be a likely problem with your current implementation.